# Angular universal duplicates failed request

Tags: angular, nestjs, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, angular-transfer-state

I am using Angular Universal with Angular 10. I've imported `ServerTransferStateModule` into my `AppServerModule` and `TransferHttpCacheModule` into my `AppModule`.

Everything works well, but if the initial request fails with some error (404, 500), it's executed on client a second time. Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: have you fixed this behaviour, to not execute the failed request on the client side ?